# override Thymeleaf in Spring Boot and can't find TemplateMode

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to override Thymeleaf in Spring Boot [using the directions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3).  However, my code needs to depend on `org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode` except that class can't be found.  How can I have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the real answer is that the class `TemplateMode` [is deprecated](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/TemplateMode.html).  I'm not sure how/why I was able to use it when depending on the thymeleaf library directly, but the solution was to substitute a string for the enum.  (Be sure to use an uppercase string)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Spring 1.4.x` or after you only need to add the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If not, you may need to include these dependencies specifying the version as `3.0.0.RELEASE`:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the parse of Html, in this case `nekohtml`:

```
    <!-- Html5 Legacy Mode -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then you should configure `thymeleaf` viewresolver, `template engine`and `template resolver` and `Enable Web Mvc as well`(Just add `@EnableWebMvc` to your configuration class).

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I'm using `Spring Boot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`; I have the `thymeleaf` dependency you list, and I'm overriding the version as in the directions by providing `<thymeleaf.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>`.  However, I am unable to `import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;`